# Not able to run a Kubernetes cluster using Windows Docker Desktop

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I installed `Docker Desktop` and enabled `Kubernetes` but not sure how to start/stop Kubernetes cluster and access it.

[image]

I have the following variable set as environment variable

```
KUBE_CONIG = C:\Users\nital\.kube\config
```

**# docker version**

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration: 1.0.4
 Version:           20.10.0
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        7287ab3
 Built:             Tue Dec  8 18:55:31 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.0
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       eeddea2
  Built:            Tue Dec  8 18:58:04 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.4.3
  GitCommit:        269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc92
  GitCommit:        ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

**# minikube start**

```
'minikube' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

**# kubectl cluster-info**

```
To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:32768: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Comment: Was there any kind of guide you have used in order to set it up?

Comment: Just google and looked into some random online tutorials